# jQuery "show/hide div on click" and "click outside to hide" not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery

// I searched but no luck, so I start a new question :)

I have:

`<a class="icon hide-text" id="btnNoti5" href="#">Notification</a>`

I want that: When I click on this `a`, it will show/hide a div and when I click outside that div, if it is visible, it hides.

I use this code to show/hide. It works fine:

```
var divNotifi = $('#divNotifi');
$('#btnNoti5').click(function(e) 
{
    if (divNotifi.is(":visible"))
    {           
        divNotifi.hide();
    }
    else 
    {         
        divNotifi.show();
    }
}
```

But when I add this code to hide the div when user click outside, it actually works, but above code stopped working: First click, it show the div. Second click: Nothing happens. The div wasn't hidden as expected.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#divNotifi");
    if (container.has(e.target).length == 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: `if (divNotifi.is(":visible"))
    {           
        divNotifi.hide();
    }
    else 
    {         
        divNotifi.show();
    }` simply use:`divNotifi.toggle()`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ try this

Comment: @gdoron and @VJD: Thank you. I know this one. But if I use `toggle()`, the problem still exists :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same event in order to stop its propagation

```
$(document).click(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#divNotifi");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});

$('#btnNoti5').click(function(e) 
{
    if (divNotifi.is(":visible"))
    {           
        divNotifi.hide();
    }
    else 
    {      
        divNotifi.show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Hugo Mallet May I know what is the meaning of container.has(e.target).length === 0, and why return false is needed in the second click event handler? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var elem = $(e.target).closest('#btnNoti5'),
        box  = $(e.target).closest('#divNotifi');

    if ( elem.length ) {          // the anchor was clicked
        e.preventDefault();       // prevent the default action
        $('#divNotifi').toggle(); // toggle visibility
    }else if (!box.length){       // the document, but not the anchor or the div
        $('#divNotifi').hide();   // was clicked, hide it !
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3EjM2/)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this. Uhmm.... Can you please explain what is the cause of the problem in my code?

Comment: The first click function isn't properly closed, and the second function does work, but not when clicking the `divNotifi` element, as `has()` checks that the `target` is ***inside*** `divNotifi`, so you would have to click an element inside `divNotifi`, and not the element itself.

Comment: Everything's OK now. Thank you for your solution and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick i like to use for thing such as this.

in the jQuery library:

```
$('#div').addClass('Class-Name');
```

whenever it is shows - add a class named "show".

and than for checking if it shows:

```
if ($('#div').hasClass('Class-Name') )
{
     // some actions
}
```

the `.hasClass()` is also a part of the jQuery library.
and the last function from the jQuery library is: `.removeClass()`

so what i am doing is:

when show - add class "show"
on click - check if has class "show" and than remove class.

hope you will find your way of using my trick :)

it makes it very easy to do things when they are so graphic.
 not much would like my method - but i do, it keeps you away from the mess.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnNoti5").click(function(){
    $("#notify").show();
});

$("#notify").click(function(){
    $("#notify").hide();
});
```